# Title window "Test™" in mac os

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want to set the title window in Mac OS using cocoa framework.
The title is like "Test™.

Can I set the "TM" in a top of "Test"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do like this.

```
NSString *test = @"Test\u2122";
[self.window setTitle:test];
```

This is also working well.

```
[self.window setTitle:@"Test™"];
```

Comment: I would generally prefer the first approach as a best practice since explicitly specifying what character to use doesn't leave it up to chance (source file encoding, etc.) - this might not matter for the *trademark* sign but can be vital for other non-ASCII characters in source files (umlauts, for example).